# Log cat in android

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I am a new android developer so I don't know how to use logcat. 
So kindly request that if you know then guide me.

Comment: THis article will be a good start:http://techbreaths.com/2012/12/debugging-android-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your device, open a console window in the tools directory of your android sdk installation and run

```
adb logcat
```

Or start an emulator and do the same.

If there's more than one device connected you needed to pass the "-s" parameter specifying the devices. get them using

```
adb devices
```

Comment: thats fine but i want to know error while emulator is running

Comment: if you run adb logcat it will log your error to the console. @Klaus: on unix adb is in "tools"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse IDE for development, you need to go to WINDOW->Show View->others->in that choose android->logcat...it will appear right beside your console....

Comment: Tanks Dear, That i know whatever u told.

Comment: But i want to know doing filter.