# Android APK installation of my new app closes back to the original screen

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

So,I finally have an app built, but my latest build of it which runs perfectly on the emulator just crashes the apk installation back to the original screen on an actual phone.  No errors what so ever.  It just closes back to the previous screen.

Comment: Post your stack trace from logcat when your app crashed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271635/log-cat-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem just downloading it from my webhost.  If I copied it over a cable it was fine.  And once I got it on the marketplace everything was fine.