# see logging while installing

Tags: android, logging

I want to see logging when I'm installin gmy Android application, because I want to see which providers are installed during installation.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you used Logcat ? Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271635/log-cat-in-android

Comment: Doesn't "adb logcat" from your terminal do the trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logcat will be your best friend... To learn everything about it in details check this article
http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/141073-learn-logcat-like-pro.html

Comment: I am glad I could help. You could accept this as answer if it helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the android documentation [LogCat Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Steps to open logcat window in eclipse :

Step 1 : Select Window options in the menu bar of eclipse.

Step 2 : Goto Show View option

Step 3 : Select Other Menu

Step 4 : In that select Android-> Logcat.

It will open a window and you can see the stacktrace of your application